# iOS create NSDate from output of Python datetime.isoformat()?

Tags: ios7, nsdate, nsdateformatter

My python backend uses the `isoformat()` method on UTC date times, which results in strings that look like `2014-01-14T18:07:09.037000`. Following other examples, I'm trying to create NSDates from those strings (passed up in JSON packets):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:S"];
NSLog(@"cycle_base %@", myFields[@"cycle_base"]);
self.cycleBase = [dateFormatter dateFromString: myFields[@"cycle_base"]];
NSLog(@"cycleBase %@", self.cycleBase);
```

I've tried variants on the `S` part (which is supposed to be fractional seconds?) of the format string, but to no avail. I always get a nil back. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iOS 7 follows the [Unicode Technical Standard #35](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns), which is a list of format patterns.

In this document you will find that the format string for fractional seconds is capitalized **S**.

```
NSString *string = @"2014-01-14T18:07:09.037000";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S";

NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:string];

NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

This will net you a valid NSDate object. Don't forget to set the proper time zone and locale on your NSDateFormatter object.

Comment: Durh and headslap. I had read UTS#35, but came to the wrong conclusion about 'S'. I thought s was basically for integer seconds, and S was for floating point seconds (integral AND fractional part).

Comment: Is there a more idiomatic way to set the GMT timezone than this `dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];`?